# Display infowindow android Maps

Tags: android, google-maps

How to display marker infowindow when map loads? when im  clicking the map name a new activity starts where the map loads.It shows the marker,the problem is i want to automatically display also the custom infowindow i created.Here's my code below: I will mark this answer for those who can fix this. thanks.

```
if (nameList.get(i).equals(selected)){

            Marker marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
             .title(nameList.get(i))
             .snippet(addressList.get(i))
             .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker_location))
             .position(new LatLng(latList.get(i), lngList.get(i))));

            marker.showInfoWindow();

            //Set Custom InfoWindow
            map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter() {


            @Override
            public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {



                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

                View myContentsView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.map_info, null);

                TextView tvTitle = ((TextView)myContentsView.findViewById(R.id.title));
                tvTitle.setText(marker.getTitle());

                TextView tvSnippet = ((TextView)myContentsView.findViewById(R.id.snippet));
                tvSnippet.setText(marker.getSnippet());

                TextView infoSnippet = (TextView)myContentsView.findViewById(R.id.moreinfo);
                infoSnippet.setText("Click for more details.");

                return myContentsView;
            }
        });

            //Open New Activity
            map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(SelectedPlaceActivity.this, PlaceDescriptionActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("placetitle", marker.getTitle().toString());
                intent.putExtra("snippet", marker.getSnippet().toString());
                startActivity(intent);

                }
            });


        }
```

Comment: Try to make marker as global variable and call `marker.showInfoWindow();` in onCreate..

Comment: how to make marker as global variable?

Comment: create a field as `Marker marker;` before onCreate method

Comment: it doesnt work, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you need an `InfoWindow` adapter. See the following example:

```
map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter(){
    // Use default InfoWindow frame
    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {              
        return null;
    }           

    // Defines the contents of the InfoWindow
    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

        // Getting view from the layout file info_window_layout
        View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_info_window, null);

        // Getting reference to the TextView to set title
        TextView note = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.note);
        note.setText(marker.getTitle() );

        return v;
    }
});
```

As you can see, you need to create a custom `layout`. In my example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/note"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textColor="#000000"/>

    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/takeMeThere"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/note"
        android:contentDescription="@string/directions"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_directions"
        android:background="@null"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Why are you checking if the user has selected the marker? According to the documentation: `By default, an info window is displayed when a user taps on a marker if the marker has a title set`. This means that this is handled for you by default. You could try assigning your custom adapter to every marker you create and then check at runtime what happens when you click on them

Comment: the custom infowindow displays if i tap the marker..what i want is to display it automatically when the activity starts.. i used showinfowindow() but it displays the default infowindow, not the custom that i made

Comment: you can't display **all** `infowindows` at the same time...looking at the documentation they tell you that `Only one info window is displayed at a time`

Comment: what exactly i want is to automatically show the custominfowindow i made on the marker i created..

Comment: OK try this: if you have a single `Marker` you have to check if it `isVisible()`. If `true`, check if `isInfoWindowShown()` (you should get a `false` here) and call `showInfoWindow()` (see this: http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker.html). If you have several `Marker`s you just need to apply this logic inside a `for` loop, but remember that you can only display one `InfoWindow` at a time

Comment: additional info here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker

Comment: I'd prefer if you edited your original question and added the code there, that way more people can help you :)

Comment: by the way have you noticed that you call `showInfoWindow()` before setting the adapter to your custom InfoWindow? Try inverting the order

Answer (score -1):

According to the documents of [Google Maps for Android V2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker):

> An info window allows you to display information to the user when they
>   tap on a marker on a map. By default, an info window is displayed when
>   a user taps on a marker if the marker has a title set. Only one info
>   window is displayed at a time. If a user clicks on another marker, the
>   current window will be hidden and the new info window will be
>   displayed. You can show an info window programmatically by calling
>   ***showInfoWindow()*** on the target marker. An info window can be hidden by
>   calling ***hideInfoWindow()***.

Comment: i did the marker.showInfoWindow() but still the default infowindow displayed not the custom info window i made

Comment: @user3875229 if you are using a custom `InfoWindow` you need to create an `adapter`